# Regex. Greedy and lazy quantifiers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
a = 'one\\two\\three.txt';
```

I want to get "three.txt". And this:

```
a.match(/\\(.+?)$/)
```

Doesn't work. Why? How can I get "three.txt"?

Comment: `Doesn't work. Why?` Because it doesn't match.

Comment: So, why don't you use `split`? `'one\\two\\three.txt'.split('\\')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex: `[\w.]+?$`
Details at regex101: https://regex101.com/r/n8HyiL/1
Or remove the `?` it's still ok!